# how to apply one ruleset to multiple functions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a quiz page to display in a browser, when the user clicks correctly an onclick gives a message for "correct" and else "no try again" and I would like to make the code simpler.

```
function colorPurple9 ()    {

    var Morado = document.getElementById('C9').value;
            if (document.getElementById('C9').checked) {
            alert("Yes!")
                }
            else {
            alert("Sorry, You got the wrong answer.") }
```

How do I list multiple functions (ex: functionOne, colorTwo, etc) into/onto a single set of rules so that I don't have to use soo many lines of code. In the form box I'm using radios with ID tags, in the above clipped code it's "C9" (and below "N2") and I want to know if I can also list more ID's, like in an array or something, to the function definition.

```
<p>The word for Two in spanish is:
    <br /><input name="word" type="radio" value="False" onclick="numberTwo()"/>Cuatro
    <br /><input name="word" type="radio" value="False" onclick="numberTwo()"/>Cinco
    <br /><input name="word" id="N2" type="radio" value="True" onclick="numberTwo()"/>Dos
    <br /><input name="word" type="radio" value="False" onclick="numberTwo()"/>Diez</p>
```

And I don't know how to force their first choice to be permanent, or use a counter, but that's optional. PLEASE.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this as `javascript`? I don't get why this is tagged `java`

Comment: there are series of question here .

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 var message = (document.getElementById('C9').checked)?"Yes!":"Sorry, You got the wrong answer.";
 alert(message);
```

[for some info go here,](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html)

hope this will help you :))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, hope it will work for your problem

```
<script>
   function numberTwo(){
       var temp= document.querySelector('input[name="word"]:checked').value;
       var result = (temp == "True") ? "Yes!" : "Sorry, You got the wrong answer.";
       alert(result );
    }
</script>
```